# IOS Take picture with front facing camera

Tags: ios, camera, image

I'm trying to build a non-realtime face detection application.

Following this article: http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/ I can load in a jpg and detect faces.

I would like to automatically take a picture every 20 seconds, then display the image in a  UIImageView* and then run the existing detect face function on it.

My question is two fold.

1. Is there an easy way to take a sample picture from the camera and
   load it into a UIImageView* without saving it?
2. How can i automate this to happen every 30 seconds with no user interaction?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using a UIImagePickerController component, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You can't automatically take a picture of the user without the UIImagePicker.

Comment: What are you trying to build? It sounds somewhat creepy lol.  But yea, you can't take pictures without additional user interaction.  Well, you can, but we call that video. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at AVFoundation Programming Guide

[AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)

This guide shows you how to use the AVFoundation to capture media.

You will need to take into account Device Rotation as the camera will display only its raw output until you rotate the output via CATransformMatrix But that is a bit more in depth than you want.

You may be able to get away with just knowing. You rotate 45° from the original point to the final rotation location.

Here is my code for my little camera testing utility.

Build a UIView and connect the IBOutlets and IBActions

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewViewContainer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playerViewContainer;
- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button3Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button4Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)swapInputsPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)recordPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *capturePreviewLayer;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDeviceInput *frontCam;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL frontCamIsSet;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL hasFrontCam;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isUsingFrontCam;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDeviceInput *backCam;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL backCamIsSet;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL hasBackCam;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isUsingBackCam;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDeviceInput *mic;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL micIsSet;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL hasMic;

@end

CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
};

CGFloat RadiansToDegrees(CGFloat radians)
{
    return radians * 180 / M_PI;
};

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

- (NSArray *) inputDevices{
    return [AVCaptureDevice devices];
}
- (NSArray *) videoInputDevices{
    return [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
}
- (NSArray *) audioInputDevices{
    return [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
}


#pragma mark - Properties

@synthesize captureSession = _captureSession;
- (AVCaptureSession *)captureSession{
    if (_captureSession == nil){
        _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    }
    return _captureSession;
}
@synthesize capturePreviewLayer = _capturePreviewLayer;
- (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)capturePreviewLayer{
    if (_capturePreviewLayer == nil){
        _capturePreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
    }
    return _capturePreviewLayer;
}


@synthesize frontCam = _frontCam;
- (AVCaptureDeviceInput *)frontCam{
    if (_frontCam == nil && !self.frontCamIsSet){
        _frontCamIsSet = YES;
        NSArray *videoDevices = [self videoInputDevices];
        for (AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice in videoDevices) {
            if ([inputDevice position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){
                NSError *error = nil;
                _frontCam = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
                if (!_frontCam){
                    NSLog(@"Error Attaching Front Cam %@",error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _frontCam;
}
- (BOOL)hasFrontCam{
    return self.frontCam != nil;
}
@synthesize isUsingFrontCam = _isUsingFrontCam;

@synthesize backCam = _backCam;
- (AVCaptureDeviceInput *)backCam{
    if (_backCam == nil && !self.backCamIsSet){
        _backCamIsSet = YES;
        NSArray *videoDevices = [self videoInputDevices];
        for (AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice in videoDevices) {
            if ([inputDevice position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack){
                NSError *error = nil;
                _backCam = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
                if (!_backCam){
                    NSLog(@"Error Attaching Back Cam %@",error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _backCam;
}
- (BOOL)hasBackCam{
    return self.backCam != nil;
}

@synthesize mic = _mic;
- (AVCaptureDeviceInput *)mic{
    if (_mic == nil && !self.micIsSet){
        _micIsSet = YES;
        NSArray *audioDevices = [self audioInputDevices];
        for (AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice in audioDevices) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            _mic = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
            if (!_mic){
                NSLog(@"Error Attaching Mic %@",error);
            }
        }
    }
    return _mic;
}
- (BOOL)hasMic{
    return self.mic != nil;
}
- (BOOL)isUsingBackCam{
    return !self.isUsingFrontCam;
}

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (NO && self.hasFrontCam && [self.captureSession canAddInput:self.frontCam]){
        _isUsingFrontCam = YES;
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.frontCam];
    }
    else if(self.hasBackCam && [self.captureSession canAddInput:self.backCam]){
        _isUsingFrontCam = NO;
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.backCam];
    }
    if (self.hasMic && [self.captureSession canAddInput:self.mic]) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.mic];
    }
}
- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    self.capturePreviewLayer.frame = self.previewViewContainer.layer.bounds;

    [self.previewViewContainer.layer addSublayer:self.capturePreviewLayer];

}

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification*) notification{
    NSLog(@"Notification Of Orientation Change\n\n%@",notification.userInfo);
    if (_capturePreviewLayer != nil){


        CGFloat rotate90 = DegreesToRadians(90);

        CGFloat rotateFinish = 0;

        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
        switch (orientation) {
            case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                rotateFinish += rotate90;
            case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                rotateFinish += rotate90;
            case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                rotateFinish += rotate90;
            case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            default:
                break;
        }

        _capturePreviewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rotateFinish, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}

- (IBAction)button3Pressed:(id)sender {

}
- (IBAction)button4Pressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}
- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.captureSession stopRunning];
}

- (IBAction)swapInputsPressed:(id)sender {
    if (!self.isUsingFrontCam){
        _isUsingFrontCam = YES;
        [self.captureSession removeInput:self.backCam];
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.frontCam];
    }
    else {
        _isUsingFrontCam = NO;
        [self.captureSession removeInput:self.frontCam];
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.backCam];
    }
}

- (IBAction)recordPressed:(id)sender {

}
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

- (void) dealloc{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Fortunately for you I just built this test app for grabbing photos.

Oh before I forget. Rending a CALayer into a graphic is as simple as

```
+ (UIImage *) captureImageOfView:(UIView *)srcView{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(srcView.bounds.size);
    [srcView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *anImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return anImage;
}
```

However I recommend you look into the AVFoundation programming guide to see how they actually capture it. This was just my own demo app and as i said. its not complete.